# Evaluate Surface Integral over this triangular surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals

When I solving the practice exercise problems at the end of the section, I stumbled upon this problem, which I have been trying to figure out how to compute the integral, but couldn't. Can someone please help?

Integrate $G(x,y,z) = xyz$ over the triangular surface with vertices $(1,0,0),\,(0,2,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$.

What I have tried:

I found the surface in question: $f(x,y,z) = 2x+y+z = 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $3$ vertices $A$, $B$ and $C$, find a parametrization for the triangle, like:
$$
u = B-A\\
v = C-A\\
(x,y,z) = A+tu+kv,\quad\text{where }t\in [0,1-k], k\in[0,1]
$$
The differential area $d\Omega$ is $||u\times v||\,dt\,dk$. Then:
$$
\iint_\triangle G(x,y,z)\,d\Omega =  \int_0^1\int_0^{1-k} G(A+tu+kv)\,||u\times v||\,dt\,dk
$$